Sensible defaults for table cell width/height?
I am writing some table display logic which needs to display paragraphs of text with table cells. (This is for a monospace terminal-based application, but I believe the question should be general.) If the user specifies a width (in %, width, etc) I can compute the width of the table, but I'm hoping to have a "reasonable" default sizing heuristic.
For instance, in this table, it's fairly clear that column 1 should be narrow and column 2 wide, which HTML handles as you'd expect:









1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.



When multiple rows get involved, it becomes more complicated:



column 1
column 2




1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.


2. This is a bit longer.
Short text.



Now there are multiple options! (See below.) Is it better to allocate more space to column 1 (which allows row 2 to be 1 line long) or to make column 1 shorter, wrapping row 2 to 2 lines but making row 1 a single line? I assume you may have to adjust your screen width a bit to see the behavior I get here, but for me, both cells 2 and 3 (in reading order) wrap to the next line, making the "worst of both worlds" where both rows take 2 lines.
Here's some ascii-art demonstrations of possible column sizes to hopefully explain what I mean. (forgive the ascii art!)


Line 1 fits in one line:
```
|1            | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod|
|             | eiusmod.                                                               |
|-------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|2. This is   | Short text.                                                            |
|a bit longer.|                                                                        |
```

Line 2 fits in one line:
```
|1                       | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed|
|                        | do eiusmod.                                                 |
|-----------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|2. This is a bit longer.| Short text.                                                 |
```

"Worst of both worlds":
```
|1                | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do    |
|                 | eiusmod.                                                           |
|-----------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|2. This is a bit | Short text.                                                        |
|longer.          |                                                                    |
```

Evenly sized 50%/50% columns (Even worse! Look at all that blank space!)
```
|1                                          | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  |
|                                           | adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.         |
|-------------------------------------------|------------------------------------------|
|2. This is a bit longer.                   | Short text.                              |
```



In particular my questions are:

How do HTML layout engines decide how to size automatically-sized tables when line wrapping is involved? Is this part of the specification or is the implementation left to the engine?
Are there alternative table-sizing algorithms/heuristics that are proposed or in common use?
Is there an algorithm that minimizes the number of total lines that a table takes up?


(Hopefully this should be SO-appropriate; I'm looking for implementation details on current software and/or specific algorithms. But if this would be better in software engineering or some typesetting SE, I'm happy to have it migrated.)

I've found This specification but I'm not sure it's current or how it actually applies to line-wrapping paragraphs (might just need to reread it a couple of times).
